# Why is it giving an error "missing left parenthesis"?

Tags: oracle, database-partitioning

```
CREATE TABLE test_table 
AS 
    SELECT * 
    FROM instrument_balance_hist 
       partition by range(instrument_id)(
       partition p1 VALUE LESS THAN (100),
       partition p2 VALUE LESS THAN (200),
       partition p3 VALUE LESS THAN (300),
       partition p4 VALUE LESS THAN (400),
       partition p5 VALUE LESS THAN (500),
       partition p6 VALUE LESS THAN (600)
);
```

I keep getting an error

> ORA-00906 missing left parenthesis

Answer (score 0):

Two mistakes in your code. First, the keyword for partitions is `VALUES` (plural), not `VALUE`. More importantly, the `as select ....` part should come after the `partition` clause (with its partition definitions), at the very end of the `create table` statement, not where you have it now.

I believe these are the only two mistakes, but if you find more, please feel free to write again.